# Limit a directory to have only 1 file?

Tags: linux, files, filesystems

Is there a way to restrict a directory to have only 1 file?

I created a specific directory for a user and I would like to limit that directory to have only 1 file. If that user wants to store new file, the user has to delete the old file before saving the new file into that directory.

Is this possible? Ideally without having to write any script and use cron job to 'monitor' the directory.

There are a few users that I would like to impose this limit to.

Any suggestion please?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you want to do that?

Comment: @schaiba I'm afraid of the answer...

Comment: looks like a quota. There is disk quota software that you can use. If disk quotas work on file-system level then there may be a mount trick that you can use.

Comment: You can have a look at this link http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/disk-quota/?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter

Comment: This is also a useful link:  https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch-disk-quotas.html#s2-disk-quotas-assigning-user

Answer (score 4):

The only way is to have a directory that the user can't write to. Create a single file in that directory and give them permission to write that file. They won't be able to remove the file nor to create another file. They won't be able to rename the file either. But they can overwrite the file, and they can change the file's metadata (timestamps, permissions, etc.) if they own the file.

```
chown root:root mydir
chmod 755 mydir
touch mydir/somefile
chown bob mydir/somefile
```

This seems completely pointless to me. There is no possible security benefit to allowing a user to have a single file; there might be a benefit if you additionally constrain the name (as I do here) but even this seems far fetched. Make sure that you're [solving your actual problem rather than some made-up nonsensical constraint](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).